# mat-table doesn't populate data comes form a http request

Tags: angular, playframework, angular-material

I have a project in angular and play, and used an angular material data table I want to fill it with data comes from my play server as a json string. And when I try to populate it nothing is showed, as if empty. I've mentioned the codebase that I used. The data is showed on the console and no errors were popped up.

appService.ts

```
  public getData() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.getDataUrl);
  }
```

table.ts

```
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'location'];


  clubModels: ClubModel[] = [];
  dataSource;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getData()
      .subscribe((clubModels: ClubModel[]) => {
        this.clubModels = clubModels;
        // check response
        console.log(clubModels.response);
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(clubModels);
      }, error => console.error(error));

  }
```

table.html

```
<table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements" [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="location">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Location</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.location}}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

</table>
```

ClubModel.ts

```
export interface ClubModel {
  name: string;
  location: string;
}
```

Console gives this output

```
(3) [
      {name: "aaa1", location: "testLocation1"},
      {name: "bbb2", location: "testLocation2"},
      {name: "ccc3", location: "testLocation3"}
    ]
```

Comment: Please show the result of `console.log(clubModels.response)`.

Comment: @N.F. I've added a snippet of the result.

Comment: Is this the result of `clubModels.response`? If so, you have to create `MatTableDataSource` from `clubModels.response` as `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(clubModels.response)`.

Comment: OK, I will post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have your data in `clubModels.response`. You have to create `MatTableDataSource` from `clubModels.response` as `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(clubModels.response)`.